# Resistor value to discharge the battery

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, resistors, lipo

I had a LiPo battery with specifications of 14.8 V, 2200 mAh, 23.6 Wh with 25 C rating.
Can any one tell me how to calculate the resistance value.

Current= 25C x 2.2 A= 55 A

Power P = VI = 14.8 V x 55 A = 814 W

P= I X I X R

R = P/(I x I) = 814 / (2.2 x 2.2)  = 169 ohms

This is what I got. Could any tell me whether the calculations are correct or wrong

Comment: Resistance value for what? Discharge to what level in what time? You know that completely discharging a LiPo battery will destroy it, don’t you?

Comment: Resistor value for discharging the battery to 11V. It is given 25 C rating

Comment: You need to show some effort in calculating this yourself and people will comment and help you refine that method. Otherwise this site becomes a homework answering service.

Comment: I already did some calculations but I am confused whether the value are correct or not.

Comment: Then show your calculations so that the experienced people tell you the result is correct or not, and at least show you the correct/better way.

Comment: 25C = 25 x 2.2 = 55A as you say. || R=V/I   = 14.8 / 55 = 0.27 Ohm. || P = V x I = 14.8 x 55 = 814 W as you say. || That's a lot of power. Thick nichrome wire may work well. || Note 14.8 = nominal value. At 25C v will be lower and will drop with discharge

Comment: 55A is the maximum current' and surely not a continuous rating. If you need the battery to discharge in about 2 minutes, use it, but understand this will greatly shorten the battery life. 2.2A is more reasonable, discharging it in an hour : I would use 1A to be kinder to the battery. Now use the battery voltage and your current , and Ohms Law, to calculate a resistance R. Hint : it isn't 169 ohms. Then calculate the power  using P=IV AND the formula you got above I*i*R. If they give different answers, find your mistake and try again.